# Using JSON in iOS before server is online - include in file as string

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I'm working on an application in iOS that gets some of its information from a server using JSON. The server's not online yet, so I'm trying to use what the developers working on the server have given me as sample code to build from. I thought the easiest way to do this would be storing the JSON response in a string and using `NSJSONSerialization`.

The code I'm trying looks as follows:

```
NSString * JSONString = @"{\"firstName\":\"John\", \"lastName\": \"Smith\", \"age\": 25, \"address\": {\"streetAddress\": \"21 2nd Street\",\"city\": \"New York\", \"state\": \"NY\",\"postalCode\": \"10021\"},}";
bool valid = [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:JSONString];
if (valid) {
    NSLog(@"Valid JSON");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Invalid JSON");
}
```

Which always logs, "Invalid JSON."

All of my research has given resources about how to get the data from a server, but nothing about testing before the server is available. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't have the trailing comma before the last `}`?

Comment: I threw your json into http://jsonlint.com/ and it was invalid.  Like @deanWombourne mentioned the comma is the issue. jsonlint is a great site to test your json to verify that it's valid, regardless of getting it from a static string, or a dynamic webservice.

Comment: Not only do you have trailing comma, but that's a JSON string, so even with typo fixed, it will fail `isValidJSONObject`. You need `NSDictionary`.

Comment: OP: how'bout researching a bit (google, ADC docs, etc.) before asking here? This is really way too basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues. First, your JSON string has an extra comma. It should be:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"firstName\":\"John\", \"lastName\": \"Smith\", \"age\": 25, \"address\": {\"streetAddress\": \"21 2nd Street\",\"city\": \"New York\", \"state\": \"NY\",\"postalCode\": \"10021\"}}";
```

Second, though, your original code has a false negative. A string will always fail `isValidJSONObject`. That method is not for validating a JSON string. If you want to use `isValidJSONObject`, you should pass it a `NSDictionary`, e.g.:

```
NSDictionary* jsonDictionary = @{
    @"firstName" : @"John",
    @"lastName"  : @"Smith",
    @"age"       : @(25),
    @"address"   : @{
        @"streetAddress": @"21 2nd Street",
        @"city"         : @"New York",
        @"state"        : @"NY",
        @"postalCode"   : @"10021"
    }
};

BOOL valid = [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonDictionary];
if (valid) {
    NSLog(@"Valid JSON");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Invalid JSON");
}
```

So, the best way to create a JSON string is to create the dictionary like above, and then invoke `dataWithJSONObject`. I generally would advise against writing a JSON string manually, because you can always introduce typos like your extra comma. I always build a JSON string from a `NSDictionary` like this, because you never have to worry about whether the string is well formed or not. `NSJSONSerialization` takes care of the hard work of formatting the string properly:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"dataWithJSONObject error: %@", error);

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"JSON string is: %@", jsonString);
```

That yields:

```
{"age":25,"lastName":"Smith","firstName":"John","address":{"streetAddress":"21 2nd Street","state":"NY","city":"New York","postalCode":"10021"}}
```

Or, if you use the `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` option to `dataWithJSONObject`:

```
{
  "age" : 25,
  "lastName" : "Smith",
  "firstName" : "John",
  "address" : {
    "streetAddress" : "21 2nd Street",
    "state" : "NY",
    "city" : "New York",
    "postalCode" : "10021"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I test by keeping a file in my resources say, test.json.  You can open it with the following code:

```
NSString *path = [NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"test.json" ofType:@"json"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                      error:&error];
```

Then call the method to convert to a JSON object.  The test file will be more readable than what you have above.  Hope this helps!

Comment: -pathForResource's first parameter should not include the file extension, that's what the second parameter is for.